# Time (and a place) for an odd-one-out puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, geography, anagram, time, odd-one-out

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #6: Is it really that [time] again?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1).</sub>

---

It is a tough task to create an 'odd-one-out' type puzzle whose solution lacks any ambiguity at all - it is all too easy for a second unintended pattern to lurk within a small number of options. To attempt to overcome that (without making the set of options a ridiculously long list), here is a puzzle where the solver is asked to find the 'odd-one-out' in eight different sets *where the **reasoning** behind what makes an option the odd-one-out is **identical** for each set*.

Moreover, once these sets are resolved you should be able to answer the question: **The name of which 8-letter country is concealed within this puzzle?**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **W** | Assumption, Large River Inhabitants, Saint James, Warm Location |
| **H** | Admiral of the Fleet Sir Fairfax, Beach, Island of the Empty Voyage(*), Ngambri |
| **E** | Adjacent to the Water, Forested Land, Holy Saviour, Sandalwood |
| **R** | Eastern Capital, Flat Land, I Saw a Mountain, Place of Fermented Mud |
| **E** | He Does Not Sleep, Port Town, The Victorious, Wisdom |
| **A** | Crocodile River, Québécois Prospector Joe(*), Smoky Bay, Where People Get Honour and Respect |
| **M** | King George III, Mrs Penh’s Hill, Our Lady of Peace, Saint Dominic |
| **I** | Big House, Monday, Stone City, The Passage (of the Lagoon) |

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are in ...

> ... **Portugal**.

Step I: Geography

> The items in the list describe the meaning of the names of various national capitals. At first, I tried to work my way through the [list of capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals) on Wikipedia, but then I found a [page that explains the etymologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capital_city_name_etymologies) of these capitals, which was a huge help.
>
>  Anyway, the capitals are:
>
>  **Asunción**, Paraguay;
>  **Paramaribo**, Suriname;
>  **Santiago**, Chile;
>  **Tbilisi**, Georgia
>
>  **Port Moresby**, Papua New Guinea;
>  **Praia**, Cabo Verde;
>  **Saipan**, N. Mariana Islands;
>  **Canberra**, Australia
>
>  **Managua**, Nicaragua;
>  **Guatemala City**, Guatemala;
>  **San Salvador**, El Salvador;
>  **Vientiane**, Laos
>
>  **Tokyo**, Japan;
>  **Pyongyang**, North Korea;
>  **Montevideo**, Uruguay;
>  **Ngerulmud**, Palau
>
>  **Harare**, Zimbabwe;
>  **Port Vila**, Vanuatu;
>  **Cairo**, Egypt;
>  **Sofia**, Bulgaria
>
>  **Bamako**, Mali;
>  **Juneau**, Alaska;
>  **Reykjavík**, Iceland;
>  **Ouagadougou**, Burkina Faso
>
>  **Georgetown**, Guyana;
>  **Phnom Penh**, Cambodia;
>  **La Paz**, Bolivia;
>  **Santo Domingo**, Dom. Rep.
>
>  **Malé**, Maldives;
>  **Dushanbe**, Tajikistan;
>  **Tashkent**, Uzbekistan;
>  **South Tarawa**, Kiribati
>
>  (An asterisk on the items means that the capital is not one of a sovereign state.)

Step II: Odd-one-out and Time

> Now to find the odd ones out in each group. The theme of the monthly challenge helps us here: We need to find the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) of each capital.
>
>  We'll see that only three cities in each group are in the same time zone, so we've found the odd one out:
>
>  **W**:   −4 except Tbilisi at **+4**
>  **H**:   +10, except Praia at **−1**
>  **E**:   −6, except Vientiane at **+7**
>  **R**:   +9 except Montevideo at **−3**
>  **E**:   +2, except Port Vila at **+11**
>  **A**:   0, except Juneau at **−9**
>  **M**:   −4, except Phnom Penh at **+7**
>  **I**:     +5, excapt South Tarawa at **+12**

Step III: Anagram

> One thing we haven't used yet is the letters before each set that spell out "Where am I?". The time difference to Greenwich time for the odd one out in each group gives us an offset to these letters. For example, shifting W four places to the "east" gives us an A, because the alphabet wraps after Z.
>
>  We get **AGLOPRTU**, which we can anagram to the answer, **Portugal**.

Appendix: Worksheet

> For what it's worth, I've pasted my "worksheet" below. It's the final state of what I had in my text editor while gathering information and trying to work out what goes on. It should be the same data as described in the steps above, but it's all in one place, which is nice, I think.
>
> ```
> W   Assumption                               -4 Asunción, Paraguay
>     Large River Inhabitants                  -4 Paramaribo, Suriname
>     Saint James                              -4 Santiago, Chile
>     Warm Location                       A *  +4 Tbilisi, Georgia
>
> H   Admiral of the Fleet Sir Fairfax        +10 Port Moresby, Papua New Guinea
>     Beach                               G *  -1 Praia, Cabo Verde
>     Island of the Empty Voyage(*)           +10 Saipan, N. Mariana Islands
>     Ngambri                                 +10 Canberra, Australia
>
> E   Adjacent to the Water                    -6 Managua, Nicaragua
>     Forested Land                            -6 Guatemala City, Guatemala
>     Holy Saviour                             -6 San Salvador, El Salvador
>     Sandalwood                          L *  +7 Vientiane, Laos
>
> R   Eastern Capital                          +9 Tokyo, Japan
>     Flat Land                                +9 Pyongyang, North Korea
>     I Saw a Mountain                    O *  -3 Montevideo, Uruguay
>     Place of Fermented Mud                   +9 Ngerulmud, Palau
>
> E   He Does Not Sleep                        +2 Harare, Zimbabwe
>     Port Town                           P * +11 Port Vila, Vanuatu
>     The Victorious                           +2 Cairo, Egypt
>     Wisdom                                   +2 Sofia, Bulgaria
>
> A   Crocodile River                           0 Bamako, Mali
>     Québécois Prospector Joe(*)         R *  -9 Juneau, Alaska
>     Smoky Bay                                 0 Reykjavík, Iceland
>     Where People Get Honour and Respect       0 Ouagadougou, Burkina Faso
>
> M   King George III                          -4 Georgetown, Guyana
>     Mrs Penh's Hill                     T *  +7 Phnom Penh, Cambodia
>     Our Lady of Peace                        -4 La Paz, Bolivia
>     Saint Dominic                            -4 Satnto Domingo, Dom. Rep.
>
> I   Big House                                +5 Malé, Maldives
>     Monday                                   +5 Dushanbe, Tajikistan
>     Stone City                               +5 Tashkent, Uzbekistan
>     The Passage (of the Lagoon)         U * +12 South Tarawa, Kiribati
> ```

Comment: Nice work :) The correct answer and a nice write-up, thanks!

Comment: ROT13 Bhg bs phevbfvgl, ubj jrer lbh noyr gb svaq bhg juvpu vgrz va gur yvfg pbeerfcbaqrq gb Fnvcna?

Comment: Thanks, all good comments. @oAlt: Its not in the linked wiki page, but searching for it as fixed expression (with quotation marks) gave me [this](https://www.indexmundi.com/northern_mariana_islands/capital.html). It's not quite the current name, but it's good enough, I think.

Comment: @Stiv: Thanks: I've noticed that you made a correction to the first set, but I think only the "Large River Inhabitants" fit that bill. Am I missing something?

Comment: Definition-wise I was aiming for ' a TZ in which they may *all* find themselves' (you'll notice Ngambri is potentially another exception like this) and [right now](https://time.is/time%20zones) (their summer) this would be the case. It means there's a hidden Easter egg in the puzzle if you used the 3's offsets in the final calculation, as an indicator the solver has the right idea but needs to adjust slightly...

Comment: I realise now that I originally had another option in 'W' that would have disambiguated this but changed it out at the last instant. At least it only breaks the Easter egg rather than the puzzle itself. Never mind!

Comment: I see what you mean. I looked only at the base offset without accounting for DST. I also tried the "good" offset, but that only misled me into trying "Syria something".

Comment: Suffice to say, my mistake not yours, and thankfully with no effect on the puzzle :) (Easter egg intended to read rot13(GEL NTNVA))

Comment: Oh, no, not your mistake. You were just more meticulous in designig the puzzle than I was in looking up the data. (And your solution explains why SN, CL and PY are in the same set.)